# How do I implement intelligent drag and drop from one JTree to another?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I have two JTrees with some mock data in there, what I'm looking to do is to be able to take each 'Job' (15663-1, 15663-2, etc) and make a node for each, with a node for each part underneath it and the components attached to each part underneath that.  In two trees, like this:

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| PARTS TO BE SHIPPED          | SHIPPING BOX                 |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|[JOB]                         |[JOB]                         |
|+------[part]                 |+------[part]                | 
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
|+------[part]                 |+------[part]                 |
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
|[JOB]                         |[JOB]                         |
|+------[part]                 |+------[part]                 |
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
|+------[part]                 |+------[part]                 |
|        +------[component]    |        +------[component]    |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

So that supposing I have two screws in the cover in job A in the 'parts to be shipped' jtree and I don't have anything in jobA in the shipping box, when I drag the screws over to the shipping box it should make an entry for jobA, make an entry for part A and make an entry for the component, then I want it to prompt for the quantity for that component and subtract that quantity from the parts to be shipped jtree.

So if I have a job called 1553-4 and it has a cover with four screws and I drag the screws into the shipping box then it should make an entry in the shipping box that says, "x screws" then prompt for the user to enter the number of screws they just packaged, if they package two screws then the jtree should change to reflect the 2 screws remaining for that job.

I have read a bunch of different drag and drop tutorials and I have some examples but I just cannot seem to get it. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

I know that I need to implement a TranferHandler but I'm not sure exactly how, there seems to be too much interface 'magic' going on and I'm really not understanding it.

This is what I have, I understand making nodes and such, here is what I have:

```
package com.protocase.examples;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;

/**
 * @author DavidH
 */
public class JTreeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addTreesAndDisplay();

    }

    private static void addTreesAndDisplay() throws HeadlessException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();


        JTree tree = new JTree(getTreeModel());
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(tree);
        panel.add(scroll);


        JTree secondTree = new JTree(getTreeModel());
        secondTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        secondTree.setDragEnabled(true);
        JScrollPane secondScroll = new JScrollPane();
        secondScroll.setViewportView(secondTree);
        panel.add(secondScroll);


        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static DefaultTreeModel getTreeModel() {
        MutableTreeNode root =  new DefaultMutableTreeNode("15663-1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode cover = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Cover");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode base = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Base");
        root.insert(cover, 0);
        root.insert(base, 0);
        cover.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2x PEMS"), 0);
        cover.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2x SCREWS"), 0);
        base.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("4x SCREWS"), 0);
        base.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("4x HANDLES"), 0);
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        return model;
    }
}
```

I'm just looking for a concise drag and drop example of dragging into a JTree and dragging from a JTree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very short, simple introduction to Drag and Drop in Swing in my own words and based on my own experience (which was mainly with drag-and-drop in JDK1.5, so new functionality might already be present).

There are two parts in a drag-and-drop operation. First there is the drag from the source component. The [`TransferHandler` of the source component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler%28javax.swing.TransferHandler%29) creates a [`Transferable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html), which is a container for the data which will be exchanged in the drag-and-drop operation. Depending on the data, there might be different representations of the data (which are called [`DataFlavor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html)s). For example if you drag-and-drop an URL to a text editor, it will most likely add the URL to the current document. But if you drop it onto a web-browser, you hope it opens that URL. So where the first is just interested in plain text, the second might be interested in a more complex object.

The second part is the drop. First it is decided whether the current location is a good drop target. It is up to the target component's transfer handler to decide whether it accepts the drop. Typically this is achieved by checking whether it can handle the data contained in the `Transferable` by asking the `Transferable` for the data for a specific `DataFlavor` (note: the `Flavor` must be known be both the source and target component). When it accepts the drop and the user releases the mouse, it can proceed with handling the data in the `Transferable`, and hopefully do something useful with it.

But as always, the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) are a very good starting point. After you went through them, you can probably come up with a more detailed question (if you still have any, as your requirement is rather trivial)

Comment: This is a great explanation. I know I need to extend TransferHandler but do I need to extend the DataFlavor? So I need to extend the Transfer Handler on my source list and make it know what to do to package it into a transferable version(which is a class that owns an object and extends Transferable) and then write a second transfer handler for the destination (unless of course the first transfer handler know how to do both)? Where do the Dataflavors come in?

Comment: The DataFlavor is just a way to indicate what 'kind of data' is available in the `Transferable` (for the sender), and for the receiver to request a particular kind of data. Think of it like a sort of label  like on a library book, where you can say "give me the mystery book" vs the "give me the romantic stuff"

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check out these tutorials.

Comment: When extending TransferHandler there are two implementations of canImport, one with transfer support and one with transfer flavors and a jcomponent. If I'm looking to transfer one of the nodes in a JTree to a JList, would I be looking to override canImport(JComponent comp, [] transferFlavours) or canImport(TransferSupport support)?

Comment: Oh man, I didn't understand why people were passing a data flavor. I kind of get it now, except for the TransferHandler part.

Answer (score 2):

On theory, I think Robin has answered your question good. So below is the implementation that I've done. To summarize, the implementation include the top two label and bottom two scrollpanes, drag from left to the right. There are still minor thing like before import happen, a dialog should appear and asking user how much quantity to drop (and then do the arithmetic operation) but I think that can be your homework? ;-) Let me know if you need further help.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class JTreeExample extends JPanel
{
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Warehouse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTreeExample newContentPane = new JTreeExample();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTreeExample()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        JLabel lbl_parts = new JLabel("PARTS TO BE SHIPPED");       
        tree = new JTree(getTreeModel());
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);        
        tree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(tree);

        JLabel lbl_ship = new JLabel("SHIPPING BOX");
        treeModel = getTreeModel();
        JTree secondTree = new JTree(treeModel);
        secondTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));        
        secondTree.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean importData(TransferSupport support)
            {
                if (!canImport(support))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();

                TreePath path = dl.getPath();
                int childIndex = dl.getChildIndex();

                String data;
                try
                {
                    data = (String) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e)
                {
                    return false;                   
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    return false;                   
                }

                if (childIndex == -1)
                {
                    childIndex = tree.getModel().getChildCount(path.getLastPathComponent());
                }

                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(data);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
                treeModel.insertNodeInto(newNode, parentNode, childIndex);

                tree.makeVisible(path.pathByAddingChild(newNode));
                tree.scrollRectToVisible(tree.getPathBounds(path.pathByAddingChild(newNode)));

                return true;
            }

            public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support)
            {
                if (!support.isDrop())
                {
                    return false;                   
                }

                support.setShowDropLocation(true);
                if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
                {
                    System.err.println("only string is supported");
                    return false;                   
                }

                JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();

                TreePath path = dl.getPath();

                if (path == null)
                {
                    return false;                   
                }
                return true;
            }                       
        });
        JScrollPane secondScroll = new JScrollPane();
        secondScroll.setViewportView(secondTree);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.add(lbl_parts, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel btmPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        btmPanel.add(lbl_ship, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btmPanel.add(secondScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(topPanel);
        add(btmPanel);        

    }

    private static DefaultTreeModel getTreeModel()
    {
        MutableTreeNode root =  new DefaultMutableTreeNode("15663-1");                        

        DefaultMutableTreeNode cover = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Cover");
        cover.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2x PEMS"), 0);
        cover.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2x SCREWS"), 0);
        root.insert(cover, 0);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode base = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Base");
        base.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("4x SCREWS"), 0);
        base.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("4x HANDLES"), 0);
        root.insert(base, 0);

        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works very well for strings and shows me what a good implementation of importData and canImport do, but if my nodes are holding objects(parts) then don't I need to implement exportData as well?

Comment: dah, it will take effort and time to find out and implement all these and including the one I mentioned in the answer. That's how we learn and grow. I would definitely love to complete this sample code unfortunately got tie up with hectic work schedule. But I will update the code in above answer with the rest of the requirements if I have free time.

Comment: Yup, that's more than enough, I worked the rest out myself. What I really didn't understand is which methods to implement/override as it seems as if there are different ways to do drag and drop.